# Firebase crash on iOS in the queue com.google.firebase.auth.serialTaskQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting this crash in the crashlytics. However I never get during testing.
Pod version is 3.16.0
[image]

Someone help me.

Comment: Post your code, indicate what line is crashing the app. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and for this question, check out this awesome guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So Jay, I don't know what line is crashing the app, because this is happening in production and stacktrace don't show what line in my code is crashing the app. If I ran locally it don't crash.

Comment: Well, without a duplicatable issue (per the requirements of this site), there's really no way to help as the crash could be caused by 100 different things. And... with no code to look at, we'd just be randomly guessing.

Comment: I understand Jay. Thanks very much.